# Definite integral over $(0,1)$ rather than $[0,1]$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm wanting to calculate a simple definite integral (but haven't done so since high-school), and am seeking some clarification.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^{2}(x-1) & 0<x<1\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I am interested in the area under the curve that is between $0$ and $1$. However, I can't just calculate $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}(x-1)\;dx$$ as the function isn't $x^{2}(x-1)$ for $0\leq x\leq1$, correct? Is there a method that I've completely forgotten about that will allow me to get what I'm after?

Thanks for your patience in answering what I'm sure is a very basic question.

Comment: You can calculate that integral from 0,1. The integral of a single point is zero. Try it out by integrating from 1 to 1

Comment: Ah, cheers. I was wondering whether that was the case. Many, many thanks!

Comment: I imagine dustin's comment has "answered" your question or are you still interested in solving the integral (if so, expand, FTC, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, dustin's comment has answered my question. I have no trouble solving this particular integral. Thanks, crash.

Comment: As another comment, note that the integral of a point may be interpreted as the area of a line, which is zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When integrating, the domain of $(0,1)$ or $[0,1]$ is inconsequential. The reason being is because the integral of a point is zero. You can test this by integrating from $a$ to $a$.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the value of an integrable function at a finite number of points will have no effect on the ultimate value of the definite integral, and below I will explain why.

Provided a function $f$ is integrable on an interval $[a, b]$, the definite integral is rigorously defined as follows:  there is a **unique** $I$ such that, for **any** given partition $\mathcal{P}$ of an interval $[a, b]$, we have:

$$L(f, \mathcal{P}) \leq I = \int_a^b f(x) \ dx \leq U(f, \mathcal{P})$$

Where $\displaystyle L(f, \mathcal{P}) = \sum_{i} (x_{i+1} - x_i)\inf \Big( \{f(x) \ | \ x \in [x_i, x_{i+1}] \} \Big)$ where $x_i$'s $\in \mathcal{P}$

and likewise $\displaystyle U(f, \mathcal{P}) = \sum_i (x_{i+1} - x_i)\sup \Big( \{ f(x) \ | \ x \in [x_i, x_{i+1}] \} \Big)$

And so with in mind, it's possible to show that changing the value of an integrable function at a single point has no effect on the value of the definite integral.  Basically, the idea is that you take your original partitions and refine them to enclose the points in question within intervals of arbitrarily small width, limiting the relevant terms to zero in the $L(f, \mathcal{P})$ and $U(f, \mathcal{P})$ summations.

For further discussion, see Chapter 6 of Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (PDFs are freely available online).

Comment: In fact, changing the value of the function at countably many points won't change the value of the definite integral.

Comment: Indeed @Math1000.  The argument would've taken a bit more work though since partitions are finite sets, so I sidestepped the issue.

Comment: The argument takes very little work if you use the Lebesgue theory ;)

Comment: @KajHansen I upvoted but just realised I didn't respond to your answer. Thank you, and thanks for the further reading. I'm always interested in reading more about maths.